# Differentiate attachment pages in search results

Tags: plugins, search, attachments

I'm using the [Relevanssi](http://www.relevanssi.com/) search plugin, which is basically a better version of the default search. Anyway when I search for something it displays everything I need it to, I was just wondering whether there would be a way to differentiate the search results for attachment pages from everything else, e.g. Display "Document: [name of attachment page]" instead of the just the name of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do it, I added the following in `content.php`. I added the second elseif statement and simple put the word Document in there before it displays the title of the page.

```
    if ( is_single() ) {
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
    }
    elseif (get_post_type() == 'attachment' ) {
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">Document: <a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
    }
    else {
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
    }
```